# autocomplete list items printing HTML out

Tags: string, jquery-ui, autocomplete, html-entities

I have a simple jQuery UI autocomplete that works fine. However when I add HTML tags to the label output string they actually print out. I've replaced them with superscript html entities ² and many other tags which also print...

```
$('#mainSearch').autocomplete({
    appendTo: ".inputWrapper",
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var customer = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/EmployeeDirectory/GetEmployees",
            data: { "filterText": request.term },
            error: function (data) { console.log('Error!'); },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                    customer[i] = {

                        label: data[i].FullName + "<a href='#'>" + data[i].Region + '/' + data[i].District + "</a>" + data[i].Center,

                        Id: data[i].UserID,
                        encryptID: data[i].UserIDEncryted
                    };
                }
            }
        });
        response(customer);
    },
});
```

Displays:

[image]

Has anyone ever seen this happen? Not sure if its the Autocomplete, the way the string is built or response()...

UPDATE:

Here is the final code that I ended up using.

```
$('#mainSearch').autocomplete({
    appendTo: ".inputWrapper",
    minLength: 3,
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "localhost/",
            data: { "filterText": request.term },
            error: function (data) { console.log('Error!'); },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.FirstName + ' ' + ui.item.LastName);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('object: ' + JSON.stringify(ui, null, 4));
        document.location.href = "/eCard/?uid=" + ui.item.UserIDEncrypted;
    }
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append(item.FullName + '<br /><sup>' + item.Region + '/' + item.District + ' ' + item.Center + '</sup>')
      .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: This occurs because the autocomplete widget populates its items using `.text()` which escapes all your html inside `label`. You can override `_renderItem` and use `.html()` to populate the items instead

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. Could you put me in the right direction to implement _renderitem with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the autocomplete widget populates its items using `.text()` which escapes all your html inside label. You can override `_renderItem` and use `.html()` to populate the items instead:

```
$.widget("my.customAutocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" ).html( item.label ).appendTo( ul );
    }
}
$('#mainSearch').customAutocomplete({ // etc.
```

Keep in mind this can be xss-prone (which is the reason the default version uses `.text()`). Unless you're 100% confident in your server validation, you might want to manually escape the Ajax results:

```
label: $("<p>").text(data[i].FullName).text() +
       "<a href='#'>" +
       $("<p>").text(data[i].Region).text() + /* etc. */
```

Comment: Whoa what an answer, thank you. I was able to get it to work with a version of your solution. 

Is it dangerous to return data inside the success function and then:
.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
          .append(item.FullName + '<sup>' + item.Region + '/' + item.District + '</span>' + item.Center)
          .appendTo(ul);
    };

Comment: Only if you sanitize the data inside the `success` function; `.append()` by itself, just as with `.html()`, doesn't escape any HTML. (sidenote: it may strip out `<script>` tags but it's still good practice to sanitize unsafe data)

Comment: When choosing a returned item the item's entire HTML is put into the field. Is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: Yeah, you can write a [custom `select` event handler](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) and update the value in it